# Rolling mean with intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, mean, rolling-computation

How can I compute efficiently the rolling mean at fixed intervals?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n=50
s = pd.Series(data = np.random.randint(0,10,n), index = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('today').floor('D'), freq='D', periods = n))
```

E.g. in the series above with an interval of 4 days and number of elements 3, the ith element of the new series  `t=t_i` will have `s_i =1/3 *( s_(i-4) + s_(i-4*2) + s_(i-4*3) )`

Comment: What is the expected output from this input? Something like `s.resample('4D').mean()`? Where `s` is the Series above `s = pd.Series(data....)`

Comment: As far as I understand with that you will basically have a 4D rolling mean computation, but I need to maintain the regular gaps in the intervals.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked out [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)? It might have what you're looking for.

If I understand correctly, here is an example with an array of 1 to 50:

```
interval = 4
window = 3
data = np.linspace(1,50,50)
arr = pd.Series(np.array(data)[::interval]) #subset data by every 4th value
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=window) #look forward 3 spaces on every 4th value
arr.rolling(indexer).mean() #take the mean of the window
```

The output would be an array [5, 9, 13, 17, ...], 5 corresponding to averaging 1, 5, and 9 and 9 being the average of 5, 9, and 13.

Comment: How does that answer the question?